# What does System property http.nonProxyHosts has been set to local|*.local... mean? And what are the implications?

Tags: java, macos, properties, fdt

I am a designer who has strayed into coding, and frequently my lack of knowledge snaggles me. Like this example: Working on Mac OS 10.5.8 in fdt 4 to build an osmf (open source media framework) media player, I suddenly started seeing this in the error log.

System property `http.nonProxyHosts` has been set to `local|*.local|169.254/16|*.169.254/16` by an external source. This value will be overwritten using the values from the preferences.

Please, what does it mean - and how can I reset it - and to what, if I need to?

Answer (score 6):

nonProxyHosts is a list of hosts that can be accessed directly and will not go through the proxy. That is the short answer.

For a full explanation you can go to [Oracle](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/net/proxies.html).